# Fix generic to take object where keys are tuple

Tags: typescript

I need help with this generic `Obj[K]` is a tuple where the 2nd item `Obj[K][1]` is the function. How can I fix this?

```
export type ThenArg<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T

export type FirstArg<T extends any> =
    T extends [infer R, ...any[]] ? R :
    T extends [] ? undefined :
    T;


type Example<Obj, Keys extends Array<keyof Obj>> = {
    [K in Keys[number]]: Obj[K] extends ((...args: any[]) => any) ? FirstArg<ThenArg<ReturnType<Obj[K]>>> : never
}


const Set = {
    alpha: ['skip', () => true]
}

type x = Example<typeof Set, ['alpha']>

/**
 * 
 * looking for x = { alpha: boolean }
 * 
 */
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqALYA7AglAcwB40A%20OAXnTlBhwBMBnOABSggFsBLR4Ir7ADNgUOAFVyAfnFwAXOgCwAKGWhIsBMlQAxLlEYx8xNDRB1sTOAENsichWVwn1Wg2YBtAcNEAlADRwAHTBNojuALrhcNI%20co7OJq4WHlHSAK4WwIICwPRxSs7oANzKpUpIKHAAoiBWHGAANnwA8gBGAFYBANLAiMxJlvhQVohEANa9EIJwbe2k9nAA3vFO7l1wAnA9fe7YaRytIpHys2tRA8wAFJfBgVaEjPKhEQCUlOShb9K6%20oaEJFg8P8fMAYGkoNg0FoiKcuuF5uR5NhgAA3ETKAC%20ZWUAGMINgDHAAMqgyhLFbWBpgDBWeTuADkjDGXDA9IClzeFHIMCgaWA4UxZQqqBAZJqdUafGFU2JoICDKsVJp9PhZQA9AAqDWODVwHVwBoQCDM7AEOCCaBwUVURaU6m0uCtI1NGxwLEFXU6tVAA)

What if Set was an object? Would it be easier?

```
const Set = {
    alpha: {
        keys: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        fn: () => true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing this requires a slight change to `Set`. As declared, the items of `Set` are arrays of a union of `string | <some function>`, which isn't good enough.

You can fix this a few ways, but the best is probably adding a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to the whole object.

```
const Set = {
    alpha: ['skip', () => true],
    beta: ['skip', () => Promise.resolve(false)]
} as const
```

Then your `Example` type can be implemented as follows:

```
type MapReturnTypes<
    T extends { [K: string]: readonly [any, (...args: any) => any] }, 
    U extends keyof T
> = {
    [K in U]: ThenArg<ReturnType<T[K][1]>>
}
```

Note that you now specify multiple keys as a union instead of as an array (`MapReturnTypes<typeof Set, 'alpha' | 'beta'>`), this is more idiomatic in my experience. If you must have an array, that's a pretty simple change:

```
type MapReturnTypesArray<
    T extends { [K: string]: readonly [any, (...args: any) => any] },
    U extends Array<keyof T>
> = {
    [K in U[number]]: ThenArg<ReturnType<T[K][1]>>
}
```

I moved the checks for the correct type from the interior of the type to constraints on the type parameters, this makes it obvious that the type is not well defined if those constraints do not hold.

One last thing, you may want to remove `readonly` from the resulting type, this can be done with `-readonly`.

```
type MapReturnTypes<
    T extends { [K: string]: readonly [any, (...args: any) => any] },
    U extends keyof T
> = {
    -readonly [K in U]: ThenArg<ReturnType<T[K][1]>>
}
```

Comment: This answer is really cool, and has a lot of great info. But I am curious if this would be easier of it was an object rather then an array. I added "What if Set was an object? Would it be easier?" at the end of the question. If it's a simple one I'd love to know how that would be done as well.

Comment: Got it! Learning this stuff through your code is so helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Object:

```
const Set = {
    alpha: {
        keys: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        fn: () => true
    }
}

type MapReturnTypesArray<
    T extends {
        [K: string]: {
            fn: any
        }
    },
    U extends Array<keyof T>
    > = {
        [K in U[number]]: ThenArg<ReturnType<T[K]['fn']>>
}

type Meow = MapReturnTypesArray<typeof Set, ['alpha']>
```